# JQTouch is working differently on my desktop than my iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova, jqtouch

So I took the time to learn JQTouch and developed my whole website for my iPhone that I am hoping to covert with PhoneGap. Now it has been working great on Safari, WebKit, and Chrome. But now I uploaded it to my web-server and and checked it on my iPhone and some of the CSS is off and it doesn't seem to be accessing the database as fast. Is this a limitation of JQTouch?

Answer (score 2):

jQTouch has nothing to do with your applications database access speed.

More likely is the difference in speed between your iPhone and your desktop machine.

Also, with the CSS, although the UIWebView used by PhoneGap is based on Webkit, it is not the same as the desktop versions and might have its own idiosyncrasies. Also the screen of the iPhone is a great deal smaller than your desktop and that might cause differences in the CSS positions, etc.